# node - How to replace part of an url

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex

I have an array of urls like this:

```js
[
 'https://subdomain1.example.com/foo-bar/', 
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar'
]
```

I need to search inside it to match the user input with the `subdomain` part of the url, I'm trying with thism line of code to achive it:

```js
 const searched = urlList.find( el => el.includes( match[1].toLocaleLowerCase() ) )
 console.log(searched.length)
```

If the input is find, I need to replace the second part of the url, in my case `/foo-bar` with `/foo-baz` or `/foo-baz-bar` to obtain a response for the user that is something like `https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar-baz/`.

At the moment I'm not sure how to proceed, is there any function in JS that can help me?

Comment: You could take a look at the `URL` constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: What do you mean with "match the user input with the subdomain part"? Do you mean that users can type in `subdomain1` and then you want to find `subdomain1.example.com/...`? Also, what do you mean when you say you need to "obtain [...] something like"? Because questions should leave things up to guesses: what do you need, _exactly_ rather than approximately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve that with a single line of code.

```js
const urlList = [
 'https://subdomain1.example.com/foo-bar/', 
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar',
 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar'
];

const findSubString = 'foo-bar';
const replaceSubString = 'foo-baz';

const res = urlList.map((url) => url.replace(findSubString, replaceSubString));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution and solved the problem
Here is my snippet for everyone that in future that need the same thing

```js
    const searched = urlList.find( el => el.includes( match[1].toLocaleLowerCase() ) )
    const url = new URL(searched)
    const host = url.host
    const responseURL = `https://www.${host}${responsePath}`
```

Comment: `toLocaleLowerCase` yields different results for different locales, so is almost certainly not what you want to use here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Finding domain and replace part of URL with regex

```
function foo() {
  let a = ['https://subdomain1.example.com/foo-bar/', 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar', 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar', 'https://subdomain2.example.com/foo-bar', 'https://subdomain3.example.com/foo-bar'];
  let seed = 'subdomain2.example.com';
  let repl = 'whatever';

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let e = a[i];
    let r = e.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)/);
    if (r[1] == seed) {
      a[i] = e.replace(/(?<=\.\w{3}\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/, repl);
    }
  }
  //document.getElementById("jj").value = JSON.stringify(a);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```